# Split string into array based on delimiters, using Regex?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split the following string:

```
s = "Whyy noot this thing? Noot!"
```

into an array using the following delimiters:

```
delimiters = [
    ' ',
    '?',
    '!'
];
```

I believe that I can use this type of expression:

```
var array = string.split();
```

and that I can use RegEx.

But I don't know what to write between the parentheses in split().

Comment: As the documentation for `split` says, you put a regexp which matches whatever you want to use as a delimiter. If you want to use two things as a delimiter, in other words to have regexp which matches any of two things, then as the documentation for regexp says, you use the alternation operator (`|`), or a character class (`[]`). Where were you having a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **[RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)** to achieve that.

```
var str = "Whyy noot this thing? Noot!";
var arr = str.split(/[\s\?!]+/);
```

Comment: No need to escape the `?`.

Comment: According to http://regexr.com/ is not necessary. It is a rule of mine always escape special characters in RegExp.

Comment: Would you mind to modify your answer so that /[\s\?!]+/ is set in the variable delimiters with comments showing which characters represent ?, ! and space, and then pass that into the split method.

Comment: The answer have the reference to MDN documentation for [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions), you can dig into the page.